# How do I fix "Error tokenizing data" error when reading Google Spreadsheet into pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets

so I have been reading google sheets into DataFrames. Older sheets are working perfectly with this methodology but any new google sheets keep giving me the same error.

> Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2

The way that has been working and continues to work on most of the google sheets I read from is the following:

```
starting_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{Sheet ID}/edit#gid=0    

csv_url = starting_url.replace('edit#gid=0','export?format=csv&gid=0')
```

Now the new url is:

```
csv_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{Sheet ID}/export?format=csv&gid=0'
```

I then try to read it in like any other csv file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_url)
```

This continues to work on multiple google sheets that I pull data from regularly.
But for some reason this has not been working on any new google sheets that get added.

I get the same error on every new sheet I try to read. Whether there are 2 rows or 1000 rows It always gives me the same error:

> Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2

Is this because of some update to google sheets itself? If so can anyone recommend another method that doesn't require a ton of effort?

Comment: Will you please show a sample of what that new url returns?

Comment: Provide the name of the columns in your CSV. Pandas seems to be trying to infer them and it's not doing it correctly.

Comment: Client, Name, Start Date, End Date